# Combining two PNG images into one image using .NET

Tags: vb.net, png

I have two (actually many) [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (.png) images in my application. Both have transparent areas here and there.

I want, in my application, to take both images, combine them, and display the result in a picture box. Later I want to save the result through a button.

So far I managed to find the two images and combine them, but it seems the transparency thing won't work. I mean, if you put one image over another, only the top image is visible as the result because, apparently, the image's background is a plain white box. Which it is not.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
    Dim Result As New Bitmap(96, 128)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Result)
    Dim Name As String
    For Each Name In BasesCheckList.CheckedItems
        Dim Layer As New Bitmap(resourcesPath & "Bases\" & Name)
        For x = 0 To Layer.Width - 1
            For y = 0 To Layer.Height - 1
                Result.SetPixel(x, y, Layer.GetPixel(x, y))
            Next
        Next
        Layer = Nothing
    Next
```

`resourcesPath` is the path to my resources folder. `Bases` is a folder in it. And `Name` is the image's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your scaling problems are possibly related to the images having a different DPI. If this is the case, you really want *DrawImage()* because it will rescale images so they match the DPI of the *Graphics* object. One caveat: if you don't provide a size to *DrawImage()* it does the same thing as *DrawImageUnscaled()* for some reason.

```
Dim result As New Bitmap(96, 128)

Dim directoryName As String = String.Format("{0}Bases", resourcesPath)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result)
    For Each imageName As String In BasesCheckList.CheckedItems
        Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.Combine(directoryName, imageName)
        Using layer As New Bitmap(fileName)
            g.DrawImage(layer, 0, 0, 96, 128)
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```

More detailed discussion is at the Xtreme VB Talk forum, where you decided to cross-post. Don't do that in the future as it increases the probability that wires will get crossed and everyone will waste time.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're trying to do this by hand. Don't. There are plenty of library routines for drawing images, and they know how to handle transparency properly.

```
Dim Result As New Bitmap(96, 128)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Result)
Dim Name As String
For Each Name In BasesCheckList.CheckedItems
    Dim Layer As New Bitmap(resourcesPath & "Bases\" & Name)
    g.DrawImageUnscaled(Layer, 0, 0);
    Layer = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work except for one thing: The picture box I use for previewing the resulting image, seems to show a "resized, bigger" version of the image. At the end I used PictureBox.Image = Result.... I don't understand why the image displays like that...

Comment: @Omega: Are your images the same size as the bitmap you're writing to?

Comment: Yes, the bitmap "Result" is 96x128, and the two bitmaps I am using to test are 96x128 as well. Yet the picture box seems to zoom the result by 2 or something...

Comment: In my picture box I have "sizeMode" on "Normal" yet it seems to scale my images...... I also tried changing it to other settings but it stays intact (scaled, which is wrong)....