# VB .NET: PictureBox scales up my images!

Tags: vb.net, zooming, scale, picturebox

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609478/combining-two-png-images-into-one-image-using-net/4609660#4609660) I managed to combine two .png images into one, and then display the result in a pictureBox image.

However, the pictureBox seems to scale up my image! Makes it bigger!

The pictureBox size is 96x128.
The two images I have combined are 96x128.
The pictureBox's SizeMode is set to "Normal"

I have noticed that even though the pictureBox's image seems to be zoomed, it is cut to keep the 96x128 rect. But I don't want it to be zoomed...

Thanks.

[image]
resourcesPath is simply the main path to my resources folder. And "Bases" is the folder in such path where I am taking the images from.

Comment: Can you make a test case?  Break this down into the raw data you are trying to put into the picture box?  If possible, save the source as an image, and upload it somewhere for us to check out?  I suspect you have a problem with your image copying, and not the picture box.  Making a simple test case will help you identify the problem.  If it doesn't, then we have something more concrete to go off of.

Comment: http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/6622/screenshot20110105at103.png
That is the function I am using which basically checks the images names from a list. resourcesPath is simply the main path to my images. Bases is a folder in such path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the preview.sizemode is set to normal.
2. Check the size of the bitmap Result just before you assign it to preview.image and make sure it is really 96x128.